# Convert square brackets notation to object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object containing preformated attribute names of a serialized `HTMLFormElement` (2-dimensional):

```
var plain = {
    id: 1,
    'items[A][Z]': 2,
    'items[B]': false,
    'items[C][][A]': 1
}
```

I want to convert the object by creating the respective sub object(s):

```
var result = {
    id: 1,
    items: {
        A: {Z:2},
        B: false,
        C: [ {A:1} ]
    }
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this is a common practise - but I can't find more ressources on the subject. How is something like that usually called and what's the best way to convert `plain` to `result`?

Edit: I've updated the examples with an `Array`. This seems to be related and is also supported by the `body-parser` of express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could split the path and reduce the path by walking the given object. If no object exist, create a new property with the name, Later assign the value and delete the splitted property.

```js
var plain = { id: 1, 'items[A][Z]': 2, 'items[B]': false };

Object.keys(plain).forEach(function (k) {
    var path = k.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = path.pop();

    if (path.length) {
        path.reduce(function (o, p) {
            return o[p] = o[p] || {};
        }, plain)[last] = plain[k];
        delete plain[k];
    }
});

console.log(plain);
```

ES6

```js
var plain = { id: 1, 'items[A][Z]': 2, 'items[B]': false };

Object.keys(plain).forEach(k => {
    var path = k.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = path.pop();

    if (path.length) {
        path.reduce((o, p) => o[p] = o[p] || {}, plain)[last] = plain[k];
        delete plain[k];
    }
});

console.log(plain);
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you! I'm now trying to implement empty square brackets (`[]`) for creating an Array (see updated question) - but I'm stuck at the `reduce` return, it seems to only work with sub objects - would you give me a hint? Or should it rather be done before `reduce`ing the Array?

Comment: i suggest to change the system to named properties for objects and numbers in brackets for array, like `plain.c[3]`, where c is an array and 3 is an index of the array, you could have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131843/accessing-or-creating-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key-without-eval)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce()` and `filter()` like this.

```js
var plain = {
  id: 1,
  'items[A][Z]': 2,
  'items[B]': false
}

var obj = {}
var result = Object.keys(plain).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (e.match(/\[(.*?)\]/gi)) {
    var keys = e.split(/\[(.*?)\]/gi).filter(e => e != '');
    keys.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
      return (i != keys.length - 1) ? a[b] || (a[b] = {}) : a[b] = plain[e];
    }, obj)
  } else {
    obj[e] = plain[e];
  }
  return r;
}, obj)

console.log(result)
```