# Update JSON object using string search

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object and need to update this object by searching the required node using a string 'locator' and then modify its value

e.g.

```
var jsonObj = {
  "School":{
    "Name":"ABC School",
    "City":"Chicago",
    "Zip":"53896"
  },
  "Students":[
    {"Name":"Student1",
     "Age": "12",
     "Gender":"Male"
    },
    {"Name":"Student2",
     "Age": "10",
     "Gender":"Female"
    },
    {"Name":"Student3",
     "Age": "15",
     "Gender":"Female"
    }
    ]
}
```

Action to be performed - 
Create a function to 
Search the object using locator string `'School.Name'` and update value to `'ZYZ School'` or
Search the object using locator string `'School.Students.1.Age'` and update value to `'18'`

```
function updateJSON(jsonObj, 'School.Name', 'ZYZ School' ){}
```

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131843/accessing-or-creating-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key-without-eval

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function updateJSON(jsonObj, locator, value) {
   var path = locator.split('.');
   if (!path.length) return;
   for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; ++i) {
        jsonObj = jsonObj[path[i]];
   }
   jsonObj[path[path.length - 1]] = value;  
}
```