# set object property with dot notation without using eval

Tags: javascript, object

I want to SET the value of an object with dot notation, but without using eval.

So from

```
const a = {
    data: {
        clients:[
            {id:1, name:'Tom'},
            {id:2, name:'John'},
            {id:1, name:'Lucy'}
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to set the name of 'John' to 'Johny'.

The dot notation syntax should be `data.clients[1].name`.

Using `eval` is a piece of cake, but I don't want to use `eval`.

The dot notation comes in a variable, so It could as well be any valid (or invalid) `string`

Comment: `a.data.clients[1].name = 'Johny'`

Comment: Ok, so use `a.data.clients[1].name = 'Johny'`, perhaps?

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I dont know the dot notation upfront, I'll need to edit my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing or creating nested JavaScript objects with string key without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131843/accessing-or-creating-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key-without-eval/40132232)

Comment: Why not just use `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just to add the variable name in front of the properties.

```
a.data.clients[1].name = 'Johny';
```

If you have a string, you could split the path and reduce the path by walking the given object. If no Object exist, create a new property with the name, or an array. Later assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (o, k, i, kk) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {});
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

const a = { data: { clients:[{ id:1, name:'Tom' }, { id:2, name:'John' }, { id:1, name:'Lucy' }] } };

setValue(a, 'data.clients[1].name', 'Johny');
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the `data.clients[1].name` is just an example. I wouldnt  know the dot notation upfront!

Comment: is `'data.clients[1].name'` a string and you like to access the properties?

Comment: exactly, It comes from a variable!

Comment: Now that is a beautiful piece of code! Thank you @Nina Scholz!