# How to set a nested key in an object from a string?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
let myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: {
   something: '1'
  }
}
```

Now, I have a string such as this:

```
"three.myNestedNewKey"
```

And I want to add the key `myNestedNewKey` to the `three` key, and add a value, let's say the number `2`. so that it ends up like this:

```
let myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: {
   something: '1',
   myNestedNewKey: '2'
  }
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
myObj["three.myNestedNewKey"] = 2
```

But it just adds one key like this:

```
let myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: {
   something: '1',
  },
  three.myNestedNewKey: 2,
}
```

So it adds just one new key with the dot in it.

I do want to keep the existing values of what is inside the `three` key, but add `myNestedNewKey`  to it.

Any ideas  how to do this in a simple way?

Comment: There are quite a few dups with quite a few answers, but one of the better ones is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589524/294949

Answer (score 0):

You can reference three after myObj then use the brackets

```js
let myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: {
   something: '1'
  }
}

myObj.three["myNestedNewKey"] = 2
console.log(myObj)
```