# JS update Array through string eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

**Hi Guys**,

I have a array with unknown amount of data in it and each data object may have many **subitems**,

```
var array = [
  {
    item: 1,
    subItem: [
      {
        item: 2,
        subItem: [
          {
            item: 2,
            subItem: [
              { item: 2 },
              { item: 3 },
              { item: 4 }
            ]
          },
          { item: 3 },
          { item: 4 }
        ]
      },
      { item: 3 },
      { item: 4 }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 1,
    subItem: [
      {
        item: 2,
        subItem: [
          {
            item: 2,
            subItem: [
              { item: 2 },
              { item: 3 },
              { item: 4 }
            ]
          },
          { item: 3 },
          { item: 4 }
        ]
      },
      { item: 3 },
      { item: 4 }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have target in string format

```
let target = 'array[0].subItem[2]';
```

I need to update this target in `array`

I can't loop because target will be random and it can 100th child.

Please help me update this target with this update

```
let update = {item: 'newitem'};
```

I can update target by

```
target = update;
```

but now how will i update value in main `array`? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t39ab0ny/)

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/q/40131843/1447675 work for you?

Comment: I can't loop because i dont know the number of child components, but its very interesting

Comment: what is the poblem by taking a string and address all properties by reduceing the object?

Comment: data target is string, i need to update main array, maybe your answer is the solution, i am checking it